# How to create a format file with initex to speed up processing time?

Tags: tex-core, format-files

I have a file called `matteo.tex` which contains lots of macros.  I'd like to create a format file with `initex` so that, every time `tex` processes a file that contains some of `matteo.tex` macros, it doesn't have to waste time processing the file `matteo.tex`. How to do it? And, then, how to make `tex` load the format generated from `matteo.tex`?

(`matteo.tex` is all written in `plain tex`).

Comment: I've found the solution by myself:  have a look at TEX BY TOPIC, A TEXNICIAN’S REFERENCE by VICTOR EIJKHOUT at page 257.

Comment: Please make this a proper answer.

Comment: @MartinSchröder What do you mean?  Can I answer my own question?

Comment: [Yes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a format file from `matteo.tex`, you should simply add at the end of `matteo.tex` the control word `\dump` and then type on the command line

`tex matteo`

Now a file called `matteo.fmt` should have been generated.  To load such file, you should type on the command line

`tex &matteo`.

If the format in `matteo.tex` does not extends `plain tex`, in order to create `matteo.fmt` you can start `tex` with the option `-ini`, i.e. you start `initex`.

Comment: Thank you for this question and answer! Can you tell if the speed-up is noticeable?

Comment: @morbusg I made up a test, running 50 consecutive times the compilation in both ways.  It resulted that the usual way took about 9 seconds, and the "``.fmt``" way  took about 7.5 seconds: so the difference is not so noticeable.  But I think that if there were more macros in ``matteo.tex``, the difference in time would be greater.
Ah I forgot to say that in Unix systems, you have to write ``tex \&matteo`` instead of ``tex &matteo``.