# How to create a format file?

Tags: texlive, format-files

How do I create a format file?

I've successfully compiled the TexLive sources under Ubuntu. Unfortunately, there seemed to be no included format files (e.g., `plain.fmt`, `pdftex.fmt`, `luatex.fmt`, etc.). So, to create one, I tried the following commands, but neither produced an "fmt" file:

```
tex -ini plain.tex

tex -ini '\input plain \dump'
```

I also tried the instructions in this link to no avail

[How to create a format file with initex to speed up processing time?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171891/how-to-create-a-format-file-with-initex-to-speed-up-processing-time)

[Compiling my own mktexfmt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89723/compiling-my-own-mktexfmt?rq=1)

By the way, I've created a directory that conforms to TDS, as well as the `texmf.cnf` file. I've done this before under Windows years ago, and I was able to generate both `plain.fmt` and `latex.fmt`. But I can't do the same under Ubuntu.

Comment: If you've compiled TeX Live from the sources, you should have `fmtutil` available and be able to do `fmtutil-sys --all`: does that work? What do you actually get from `tex -ini plain.tex`: 'doesn't work' is a bit vague. (Aside: I also wonder why you are compiling from the source! It might be worth saying how much of TL you downloaded/compiled that way.)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the comment. "fmtutil-sys" is not available; I do have the executables tex, luatex, xetex, pdftex, tangle, weave, etc., but not "fmtutil-sys". "tex -ini.." does not generate the format file; that's what I meant by "doesn't work. As for TL, I've downloaded the whole sources and compiled them because I wanted to create my own minimal distribution and modify the sources, partly out of curiosity. I don't have luck though doing it under Windows using MingW, which was my original plan.

Comment: @knight_owl: The sources don't install a usable system. So I'm not surprised that "it doesn't work" - what does that mean, exactly? Show us the output of the commands, please.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I see you've edited but we still need some real detail, for example a `.log` file from TeX.